# How to add multiple right braces to matrix and over/underbrace outside of matrix

Tags: underbrace, overbrace

[image: Not sure how to add side braces and multiple over braces and underbrace for the matrix A]
[image: This is the matrix code for the matrix I currently have]
Not sure how to add side braces and multiple over braces and underbrace for the matrix A

[image: What I currently have is braces inside the row vector, not sure how to make outside of the row vector]
What I currently have is braces inside the row vector, not sure how to make outside of the row vector
Not sure how to type up these matrices in latex